# Understanding time complexity to replace string characters

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

This is my solution in javascript to remove all occurrences of 'b' and 'ac' in a string but I am able to come up with time complexity esp. when removing all occurences for 'ac'. Could someone explain ?

```
function removeChars(input) {
  let result = input;

  
  result = result.replaceAll('b', '');   // tc = O(n) where n is length of string. string of all b's
  

  while(result.indexOf('ac') !== -1) {  // number of ac ? what if aacacacc
    result = result.replaceAll('ac', '');    // replaceAll has time complexity of O(n)
  }
  return result;  // space ~ O(n)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can consider one of the most special cases: `input = aaa...aaaccc...ccc`.

Assume the input string has length `n`, there will be `n / 2` occurences for 'ac'. The statement of `result = result.replaceAll('ac', '');` will be executed `n / 2` times. The time complexity of `replaceAll()` is O(n), thus the overall time complexity is O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present, so the worst case will be *O(N)*, and you `replaceAll` inside the loop so the Big-O is *O(N)*, the total Will *O(N^2)*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf